# Count and sort by number of times something appears in an array

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sorting, count

PHP/MYSQL

This may be quite simple, but I've searched and searched but can't find anything to fit.

If I have a table which contains certain fruits (all in the same field) say for example "orange", "apple", "grape", and "banana". But they all appear multiple times in no particular order.

After I run my query, is it possible to output the number of times each appears in DESC order?

Example output:

```
Orange 14
Apple 12
Grape 8
Banana 4
```

Sorry I have not provided any code, but I'm self taught to a very basic level and I don't even know where to begin after running the initial query.

Comment: This is a very basic `group by` query.  If you are going to use SQL effectively, you should learn the language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming ur table schema is `Fruits( id, fruit_name )`

Your query should be :-

```
SELECT fruit_name, count(*) AS total 
FROM Fruits
GROUP BY fruit_name
ORDER BY total DESC
```

Comment: Can't believe it was that simple, thank you so much.

Comment: Just to go a step further, given the table schema is Fruits( id, fruit_name ). Is it possible just to work on the last 10 entries?

Comment: @teddytash if the ID is an auto increment field then you can just add "where id >= (select max(id)-9 from fruits)" (without the quotes)

Comment: @Brian DeMilina and Aman - It's not easy trying to do this being self taught but you guys have helped me out here.  Really appreciated.